# Groovy JsonSlurper Issue involving commas in JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I have some JSON coming into my controller, call it **params.formData**, it looks like this:

```
'{"year":"2014","resource":["Smith, John","Foo, Bar"]}'
```

My code to parse it:

```
....
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def data = slurper.parseText(params.formData)
...
```

**data** looks like:

```
[resource:["Smith", "John", "Foo", "Bar"], year:"2014"]
```

Notice that there were two JSON entries, and the parser made it into an array of four entries.  I want it to look like this:

```
[resource:["Smith, John", "Foo, Bar"], year:"2014"]
```

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it does.

```
assert data.resource.size() == 2
```

Should prove me right ;-)

My guess is the output of printing data:

```
[resource:[Smith, John, Foo, Bar], year:2014]
```

Confused things. It looks like 4, but it's 2

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this behaviour. Run this code in the Groovy console

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '{"resource":["Smith, John","Foo, Bar"]}'
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def data = slurper.parseText(json)

assert data.resource.size() == 2
```

The assertion passes, indicating that there are 2 entries. Why do you think there are four?

Comment: Maybe because it looks a bit tricky when you'll try to println the data :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a Map rendering "optical illusion"

```
data.resource.each {
    println it
}

Smith, John
Foo, Bar
```